# IE9 CSS layout issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having some layout issues with IE9 and I can't seem to get to the root of it. I am using Foundation 5 but I don't think that is the issue. I have this in a Foundation grid as large-12 so there is plenty of space.

This is what it looks like in IE9; There shouldn't be a gap.

[image: IE9 screenshot]

HTML (this is just the html for 2 cards/links):

```
<div class="linkPanel">
    <div class="lastMod">
        <span id="last_modified" class="thisDate">Wed, 17 Jun 2015 09:39:13  CDT</span>
        <div class="newItem">
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <a href="#">Claims Emergency Contact</a>                                                                                                          
</div>
<div class="linkPanel">
    <div class="lastMod">
        <span id="last_modified" class="thisDate">Wed, 17 Jun 2015 09:39:13 CDT</span>
        <div class="newItem">
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <a href="#">Claims Emergency Contact</a>                                                                                                          
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.linkPanel {
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    cursor: pointer;        
    float: left;            
}
.linkPanel a {
    padding: 14px 10px 0 19px;
}
.newItem {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}
.thisDate {
    display: none;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. If you happen to see it or know of some specific IE9 bug that would cause this, I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Looking at what you have provided there could be a lot of reasons. It would be helpful if you provided more of the CSS code. For example what does the .lastMod class do? Also are you clearing your float for the .newItem? That could be causing issues as well.

Comment: Thanks @crazymatt. The .lastMod doesn't have any css associated with it. It is there for some js. Yes I am clearing the float.

Answer (score 0):

*I think it's a container / width thing. It seems like you might be with holding some code (can we see parent items?), but this is what I would guess:*

What ever is the container wrapper for the 2-columns (or if you have one for each 1 column), add a `width:` maybe even also add a `min-width:` make sure it is declared by `position:relative;` so it's the stable wrapper of the 2-columns. I'm assuming in IE-9 since things render slightly different, it could be resolving with not enough space, forcing that odd item up. You can also try increasing the width of said wrapper by a few pixels, maybe allowing for enough for it to snap into place in IE-9.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It wasn't a spacing issue. Plenty of room. To fix this I added a height to .linkPanel and that cleared it right up.